# Predicate not pushed into left join on MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, join, query-optimization, predicate

I am trying to optimize some complex view, which was reduced to a simple issue.

MSSQL is left joining two tables, partly on a main query predicate. The problem is, that server doesn't use this predicate for the joined table until it is actually left joining and the result is more data read from the table and the query is slower.

### Sample data

To show this problem, I created simple example that represents part of the view data:

```
create table A (
  ID numeric not null identity,
  D date not null,
);

create table B (
  ID numeric not null identity,
  A_ID numeric not null,
  DATE_FROM date not null,
  DATE_TO date not null
)

declare @i int = 0
declare @j int
declare @k int
declare @batch int = 1000
declare @a_id int
declare @month date 

begin transaction
while @i < 2000
begin
  set @j = 0
  set @month = dateadd(mm, @i, '1950-01-01')
  while @j < 20
  begin
    insert into a (d) values (@month);
    select @a_id = scope_identity()

    set @k = 0
    while @k < 30
    begin
      insert into b ( a_id, date_from, date_to                                        )
      values        ( @a_id, @month, dateadd(dd, round(rand() * 100, 0), @month) );
      set @k = @k + 1;
      if (@batch = 0)
      begin
        set @batch = 1000
        commit;
        begin transaction
      end
      set @batch = @batch - 1;
    end
    set @j = @j + 1;
  end
  set @i = @i + 1;
end
commit

alter table A add constraint A_PK primary key (ID);
alter table B add constraint B_PK primary key (ID);
alter table B add constraint A_FK foreign key (A_ID) references A(ID);
create index AI on A(D);
create index BI on B(A_ID, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO) include (ID);
```

### Sample (slow) query

The query I am basicaly trying to optimize is very simple:

```
select A.id
,      B.id
,      B.DATE_FROM
,      B.DATE_TO
from      A
left join B on B.A_ID = A.ID and A.D between B.DATE_FROM and B.DATE_TO
where A.D = '2000-01-01'
```

And the result takes around **80ms** with a query plan like this:
[image]

### Basically same (fast) query

If I use the predicate date right in the left join:

```
select A.id
,      B.id
,      B.DATE_FROM
,      B.DATE_TO
from      A
left join B on B.A_ID = A.ID
        and '2000-01-01' between B.DATE_FROM and B.DATE_TO
where A.D = '2000-01-01'
```

Suddenly MSSQL can actually use it and speeds up to **0ms**:
[image]

### Question

If I had remove/change the indexes `IA` or `IB` or the amount of data, both plans looks different, but the same persists: the joined table is being read without predicate and the query is slower.

The question is **why MSSQL creates different plans for those queries** and **how can I join more effectively in the first sample?** Please note that I can not use the second query, because it is just part of a view, in which the predicate is not known.

### Edit 1

Regarding Allan's answer there is one more test. If I use only `ID` and `DATE_FROM` in the predicate then the optimizer filters `B` on the predicate as well:
[image]

Note that this change returns generally different result, but here it returns the same (unimportant here, I guess).

### Edit 2

Regarding TT's comment (and Allan's answer as well) I changed the test data to get more randomnes, so the `A.d` doesn't always mach the interval begining in `B`. I only changed the `insert into A`:

```
insert into a (d) values (dateadd(dd, round(rand() * @j, 0), @month));
```

And than the optimizer started to work as expected:
[image]

Comment: The fast query is just better; you don't need to reference `A.D` in the join clause, you already know you want a certain date between B-fields.

Comment: @TT. the optimizer could make that determination. Propagating equalities is usually within reach.

Comment: Voting to move to DBA. Pure query optimization questions are better served on that site.

Answer (score 1):

I have to put this as an answer because it's getting to big for a comment:

SQL Server does it differently because the two queries aren't the same.
For you they might be semantically in your test example - but they're not for the optimizer/compiler.
The JOIN clauses are handled before the WHERE. This is especially visible in OUTER JOINs where parameters in the ON clause will mean different things than if they were in WHERE clause, anyway....

So in your first one you say - give me all on the left and do an outer join with the right ON the matching date column (and give me NULL where there is no match). Then at the end it says WHERE the date is something specific.
However, in the second you add an additional constraint and say give me all on the left and do an outer join on the right AND date is between a specific date (and give me NULL where there is no match). And then at the end the WHERE is handled.
So subtle, but significant different.

You can quickly see that they're different because you do not have to go through the rule engine for compilation and optimization, but the engine has to follow its rules.

However, without more information about what else is going on, any suggestion I can give to "optimize" might be irrelevant due to the other parts of the query not shown.

Based on the explanation I would think you will even end up having to refactor your query *entirely* and if possible into multiple sections.
Then you can utilize some temporary tables (not table variables), so you can do all INNER JOIN to begin with, and then do the OUTER JOINs when all INNER JOINs are handled.
This way will allow you to filter a lot of data away and use the temporary result on top of the OUTER JOINs.
Whether you are allowed to do so in your situation or not, I don't know - but it might be that given your "constraints" that the problem is "unsolvable".

Comment: you say _JOIN clauses are handled before the WHERE_, but I am not sure if you mean physical operations by that. Please see the **Edit 1** of my question.

Comment: Can there ever be a situation where the two queries return different results? Can't think of any right now.